# Unable to Catch Stripe Errors if user enters wrong card details

Tags: php, arrays

For Charging customers I built this code and get a PCI Compliance server.
Everything works as expected when user enters right cc information but when user inputs any wrong information like cc expiry or incorrect card number it fails to catch error and throw error on page like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe_CardError' with message 'Your card number is incorrect.' in /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php:148 Stack trace: #0 /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(254): Stripe_ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{? "error": {?...', 402, Array) #1 /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(104): Stripe_ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{? "error": {?...', 402) #2 /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/ApiResource.php(126): Stripe_ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/tokens', Array) #3 /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/Token.php(26): Stripe_ApiResource::_scopedCreate('Stripe_Token', Array, NULL) #4 /home/treehouse/workspace/Proccess-Card.php(54): Stripe_Token::create(Array) #5 {main} thrown in /home/treehouse/workspace/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php on line 148

```
<?php
$ccn = $_POST['ccn'];
$ccm = $_POST['ccm'];
$ccy = $_POST['ccy'];
$cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
$api = 'sk_test_yEW8dYhX4xiAzpaRiWCr7UbC';
$amount = '$_POST['amount'];
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey($api);
$token = Stripe_Token::create(@array(
"card" => array(
"number" => $ccn,
"exp_month" => $ccm,
"exp_year" => $ccy,
"cvc" => $cvv
)
));

try {
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $amount, // amount in cents, again
"currency" => "usd",
"card" => $token,
"description" => "payinguser@example.com")
);
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
?>
```

I also tried doing all these things with latest stripe library 3.4 and use code to charge stated on the site.

```
<?php
$ccn = $_POST['ccn'];
$ccm = $_POST['ccm'];
$ccy = $_POST['ccy'];
$cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
$api = 'sk_test_yEW8dYhX4xiAzpaRiWCr7UbC';
$amount = '$_POST['amount'];
require_once('./stripe/init.php');
Stripe::setApiKey($api);
$token = \Stripe\Token::create(@array(
"card" => array(
"number" => $ccn,
"exp_month" => $ccm,
"exp_year" => $ccy,
"cvc" => $cvv
)
));
try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $amount, // amount in cents, again
"currency" => "usd",
"card" => $token,
"description" => "payinguser@example.com")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you noticed that you have an extra `'` at `$amount = '$_POST['amount'];` ?

Comment: I remove extra ' but have same error yet nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Try Catch for Stripe_Charge::create

```
  <?php
    $ccn = $_POST['ccn'];
    $ccm = $_POST['ccm'];
    $ccy = $_POST['ccy'];
    $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
    $api = 'sk_test_yEW8dYhX4xiAzpaRiWCr7UbC';
    $amount = '$_POST['amount'];
    require_once('./stripe/init.php');
    Stripe::setApiKey($api);
    try{
    $token = \Stripe\Token::create(@array(
    "card" => array(
    "number" => $ccn,
    "exp_month" => $ccm,
    "exp_year" => $ccy,
    "cvc" => $cvv
    )
    ));
   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "card" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
    );
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
      $body = $e->getJsonBody();
      $err  = $body['error'];

      print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
      print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
      print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
      // param is '' in this case
      print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
      print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
      // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
      // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
      // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
      // Network communication with Stripe failed
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ $e) {
      // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
      // yourself an email
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    }
    ?>
```